# Extracting useful energy inline to a pressure relief valve?

Tags: energy, pressure, work, volume

So imagine if we have a pressure vessel being pressured with a pump.
Let's say there is a pressure relief valve that's necessary in the design.
Would you actually be able to extract useful work from putting an expander in line to the pressure relief valve?

I want to say no because any additional constrictions would just be more work the pump would have to do.

However on the other hand, when there is no requirements on flow and you have all the time you want, the pressure will equalize in the system's volume, and restrictions don't matter as there is a limited volume of the system, and a specific volume of gas in that system.

So it seems like you could put an expander over a pressure relief outlet and recycle energy.

Is this correct? if so, couldn't you just put expanders/generators in air conditions instead of expansion valves?

Comment: Are you asking if energy is conserved in the case of gas being pumped through various valves, pistons, flow restrictors, and etc.? Yes, it is. Though you may have to account for heat loss due to things like friction, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure relief valves are safety devices that prevent rupture of equipment and occasionally prevent explosions.  Their design typically accounts for any downstream back-pressure, and that back-pressure should be minimized, precisely because it is a safety device.  It may even be illegal to install downstream equipment that would impede process flow from the device.  I recommend that you consult OSHA 1910 (management of change) to determine if this issue is explicitly addressed.

In the event that your suggestion is legal, there is an important consideration to keep in mind.  When a given process is running normally, the pressure relief valve is not open, and indeed, pressure relief valves should not open at all if process conditions remain within their designed range.  This means that you want to install an expensive piece of rotating equipment at a spot in the process where it either will not be used at all, or will be used VERY infrequently.  No manager wants to waste money on a given process, so such an idea is very impractical.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, this is a purely theoretical question in an attempt to get my head around physics. The pressure relief valve in question isn't used in this thought experiment for its intended purpose, I only mentioned it to highlight that the pressure would be let out in general.

Comment: For the reasons I outlined in my answer, you will never see a pressure recovery device downstream of a pressure relief valve.

Comment: Your answer in its entirety had to do with the safety aspect of pressure relief valves. This isn't about pressure relief valves or any safety aspect. It's about using a pressure recovery device instead of a thermal expansion valve, which is what i tried to say in my first comment.